# django serializer manytomany field validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer and i want to validate if atleast one is selected from the many to many fields . I have two ManyToMany fields in the objects which are levels and categories.

My serializer:

```
class WorkflowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Workflow
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'levels', 'categories')
        read_only_fields = ['id']
        depth = 2


    def validate_categories(self,categories):

        if len(categories)==0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You haven't selected any category,Please select alteast one")

    def validate_levels(self, levels):
        for level in levels:
            if len(level['permissions'])==0:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("You haven't specified a permission for the level")
        return levels
```

Rn now the validationjs are not working as it should.The data is getting saved even if none is selected in the Many to Many field

Comment: I would move this code to the general `validate()` - can't check it right now, but from what I recall the `validate_{field}` is not called at all if field is **empty** or **None** - alternatively you could try to override those fields and set them to not allow empty/null values.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
  def validate(self, data):
        if len(self.initial_data['categories'])==0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("category not selected")
        for level in self.initial_data['levels']:
            if len(level['permissions'])==0:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("No permission added for a level")
        return data
```